# MVC3 Razor URL.Action Parameter Value with forward slash. giving error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, controller

Its a small question on MVC3 Razor, I have a string ID like "a/b" when I am trying to call details or delete method of Controller. Getting error as system assuming "a/b" as 2 parameters but I have to pass this in one string value parameters.

--Edit

```
< a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Search", new {id = "a/b"})">Details </a>
```

My Controller/method is like
Search/Details (string id)

And I want to send id = 'a/b' . but .Net assuming it as 2 parameters in URL.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that forward slashes are not automatically encoded, and the reason is probably because even if they are encoded (%2f), by the time they reach the routing engine they have been decoded back to a forward slash. (Search for Robj in [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx) by Phil Haack (former manager on the MVC team)).

However, [.NET MVC Routing w/ Url Encoding Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225563/net-mvc-routing-w-url-encoding-problems) poses the same problem, and it appears that the only way to solve this is to insert the encoded slash into a query string. Something like this:

```
< a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Search")?id=@Url.Encode("a/b")">Details </a>
```

and then, dealing with it in your method by accessing:

```
Request["id"]
```

Comment: I am using webgrid and have a link to call details but my ID is like 'a/b'. Please suggest how to escape in MVC3.
My request is like : @Url.Action("Details", "Search", new { id ="a/b" }
When I am clicking on link its looking for url "Search/Details/a/b" and obviosly it did not get anything.

Comment: I tried this but its giving me same error. 
 @Html.ActionLink("Text To Display", "Action", "Controller", new {id="a//b"}).
as .Net intrepret again it in 'a/b'

Comment: This is odd. My understanding is that the value should be escaped.

Comment: Can you try wrapping the string in this: Html.Encode("a//b")?

Comment: Nope same error. 
I am using < a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Search", new {id = "a//b"})">Details </a>

Comment: < a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Search", new {id = Html.Encode("a//b")})">Details </a> does not work? That is supposed to force the encoding. I will spin up a quick test to try this myself.

Comment: OK, I figured it our, you shouldn't use Html.Encode, you should use Url.Encode. I have verified this locally. Updated my answer, please let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks Justin, Now it creating link as 
Search/Details/a%2fb
But I am getting error "Bad Request" on click this link any idea.

Comment: It looks you are out of luck. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/04/10/upcoming-changes-in-routing.aspx  Search for Rodj and you will see that Phil Haack says that this comes through decoded even if it WAS encoded. Sorry.

Comment: Actually, I updated my answer above to give a POSSIBLE solution. As a side note, I do see that you are new, so welcome, and keep in mind that answers are appreciated with an accept checkmark and an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an escaped URL, so that parameter would be `a%2Fb`

Comment: Are you saying that this doesn't work `@Html.ActionLink("Text To Display", "Action", "Controller", new {id="a%2Fb"})`?

Comment: Yes, when I am using "a%2Fb", on click button getting error "Bad request"

Comment: Hi Lazarus, sorry about confusion. I was using Url.Action
in case I am using @Html.ActionLink("Text To Display", "Delete", "CaseSearch", new { id = "a/b" }). Method is called but parameter valus is Null. Please suggest